# org mode export to markdown and character entity problems

Tags: emacs, markdown, org-mode

I need to export a lot of documents written with `Emacs-Org`to markdown. I am using the export via-pandoc. Everything works fine except for the multitude of special symbols written using org-syntax. Just an example the β character which in org is written `\beta` in the exported document I have `\\beta` instead of `&beta;` . Is there a way to fix this instead of manually change few hundreds of symbols ?

Answer (score 0):

To replace text in a single file, you simply type `M-x replace-string`. To replace strings for multiple files, follow the following [instructions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Replacing-text-across-multiple-files.html):

> 1. Assemble a list of files you want to operate on with either find-dired, find-name-dired or find-grep-dired.
> 2. Mark all files in the resulting Dired buffer using t.
> 3. Use Q to start a query-replace-regexp session on the marked files.
> 4. To accept all replacements in each file, hit !.

Comment: how to query-replace-regexp in a way to obtain `\\symbol ---> &symbol;` ?

Comment: You type `\\\\symbol`instead of `\\symbol`. `\\` is a special symbol and needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use pandoc but with a similar problem exporting org-mode files to html I found I needed to enter the entities as '\beta{}' and not just as '\beta' (without the quotes)